# Why does strftime change my times in R?

Tags: r, csv, strftime

I have a dataframe containing a time column in with a 24 hour clock:

```
canopy_understory trap_no           file_name     date     time   temp light_intensity
              <chr>   <int>               <chr>   <dttm>   <time>  <dbl>           <dbl>
1                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt1 16-01-09 14:00:00 35.542              41
2                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt2 16-01-09 15:00:00 28.953               4
3                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt3 16-01-09 16:00:00 27.468               1
```

In order to remove the seconds column I run this code on it in R:

```
all_files_hobo$time <- strftime(all_files_hobo$time, format = "%H:%M")
```

After I run this code, I have the following dataframe

```
canopy_understory trap_no           file_name     date  time   temp light_intensity
              <chr>   <int>               <chr>   <dttm> <chr>  <dbl>           <dbl>
1                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt1 16-01-09 06:00 35.542              41
2                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt2 16-01-09 07:00 28.953               4
3                 c      11 trap11c_160314.txt3 16-01-09 08:00 27.468               1
```

As you can see, the seconds are gone and the column has changed from  to , but the times are also different. This is problematic. I could just add 8 to each time, but I'm afraid that there is something more insidious going on here and that things will get messed up in the near future. Why is strftime changing my times?

Comment: Reading the man I'm thinking its a timezone issue, but I still have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: set the timezone using the `tz` argument of `strftime`

Comment: What do I set the timezone to make it not change anything?

Comment: most likely the current timezone that you're in, or UTC. See `OlsonNames()`

Answer (score 3):

Since the time column contains no TZ information, UTC is assumed and then `strftime` uses the difference between that and your local TZ in the conversion.

So try:

```
all_files_hobo$time <- strftime(all_files_hobo$time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

Answer (score 0):

or try

```
library(lubridate)
all_files_hobo$time <-hms(all_files_hobo$time)
```